# Migrating Outlook email to a new computer

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am new to doing IT Support.

Am I correct in understanding that if I want to migrate emails to a new computer, I need to export a PST file from the old computer and import it into the new one in order to get it to show the emails on the new computer?

(I was told that if I did not export and import the PST file, the new computer will only show emails from the last 3 months, depending on configuration)

**For Exchange Online (Office 365)** - Is my understanding that I do not need to export the emails because they will automatically be synced to the new computer correct?

Comment: What mail server is the "old computer" using? On premise exchange? Correct about O365, you don't have to do anything with a pst, just sign into the account and it will sync to what you set it (all mail, 18 mos, 12 mos, 6 mos, 3 mos). It's called cache mode.

Comment: Yes sir. The old computer is normal exchange and new computer is also the normal exchange. So i need to export to PST, then in the new computer import it right ? Once imported, it is no longer a PST right ?

Comment: Come on guys...Anyone ?

Comment: All emails should sync with the exchange server no matter what. The only time you would need to export/import a pst is to transfer mail from an old exchange account into the new exchange environment. As long as the exchange server is staying the same for the account, the user just needs to log in to outlook on the new computer and it will grab all their mail.